# Handle event after .NET MAUI page has become visible

Tags: maui

I have a `ContentPage` which requires some "heavy lifting" before its data can be shown.

So, my idea was to have an `ActivityIndicator` on the page visible until the data is ready to be displayed.

I'm trying to figure out a suitable *event* to use for this purpose.

I can't use the `Appearing` event as that happens right *before* the page becomes visible.

Same goes for events like `Loaded` or `NavigatedTo`, as they all fire *before* the page becomes visible.

So, my question is: is there a suitable event for performing some long-running task *after* a page has loaded and become visible to the user?

Edit: The long-running operation is `async`, but it seems the data-binding to a `CollectionView` on the page is what is causing perceived lag when the page loads, which is why I'd like to hold off on data-binding until the page is visible with the `ActivityIndicator` spinning.

Edit 2: I might have been chasing a red herring. The UI stutters seem to be caused by some SVGs that were loaded in the `CollectionView` template. Not sure why, perhaps related to the PNG conversion. Either way, I don't think I actually *need* the type of event I was originally looking for.

Comment: Well if the long-running task is Async(obviously) then why can't you run it OnAppearing?

Comment: It is async, but I'm trying to figure out why this specific page causes stuttering and a delay when navigating to it, so I wanted to see if I could rectify it by loading a "blank loader page" and then initiate the async operation. For the impression of performance, I want all processing power to go the UI thread and hold off on everything else, if that makes sense.

Comment: So what you should do in such situations is Run this through Task.Run which isn't awaited so its Fire and Forget but through that method, you raise a bool flag that shows an indicator for the loading. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I think one of the culprits is the data-binding to a `CollectionView`, that's what seems to be causing the delay, not the data-fetching itself. So, I'd like to hold off on the data-binding until after the page is visible and the `ActivityIndicator` is spinning.

Comment: Why don't you add your View and ViewModel and let's see what we can do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *was* a red herring.

The problem wasn't related to `CollectionView`, but rather the SVG images (icons) that were rendered on the page.

Because of the SVG's having large *view boxes*, the **Resizetizer** in .NET MAUI converted them to very large PNGs, which when rendered caused the UI to become choppy.

Setting `BaseSize` attributes to more reasonable icon sizes on the `<MauiImage />` elements in `.csproj` made the UI snappy.

Comment: Thanks, this information will be useful for my upcoming development.

Answer (score 11):

## Option 1

One approach that I sometimes use for this is the following.

The heavy-lifting (loading) goes into your ViewModel, but you get a handle to the LoadAsync() method before even instantiating the View. You can bind your ActivityIndicator to an IsBusy property. Once everything is loaded, you can hide the ActivityIndicator.

**ViewModel**

```cs
private bool _isBusy;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get => _isBusy;
    set
    {
        _isBusy = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public async Task LoadAsync()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    //Some long running operation 
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

**View**

```xml
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
```

**Navigation**

In the code where you instantiate the View and ViewModel, do the following:

```cs
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
var loadTask = viewModel.LoadAsync();
await Navigation.PushAsync(new View(viewModel));
await loadTask;
```

Or simplified as:

```cs
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
await Navigation.PushAsync(new View(viewModel));
await viewModel.LoadAsync();
```

## Option 2: Defer Data Binding

Do **not** set the `Binding` for the *ItemsSource* property in XAML, but only in the code-behind, like follows:

*Code Behind*

```cs
private readonly ViewModel _vm;

public View MyView(ViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = _vm = vm;
    LoadAfterConstruction();
}

private async void LoadAfterConstruction()
{
    _vm.IsBusy = true;
    await _vm.LoadAsync();

    //only set the binding of the CollectionView after loading completed
    MyCollectionView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, nameof(MyCollection));

    _vm.IsBusy = false;
}
```

*XAML:*

```xml
<CollectionView x:Name="MyCollectionView" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#populate-a-collectionview-with-data

In either case, your view becomes visible and then loading sets in.

***Note:** This code is not written for optimization or MVVM-correctness.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That's conceptually close to what I'm doing now, although it doesn't solve the problem of deferring the data-binding of the `CollectionView` until the page (and the `ActivityIndicator`) is visible on screen.

I've moved the data-fetching to app start for now (just to take it out of the equation) to focus on a "snappier" way of loading the page even if the `CollectionView` data-binding takes time.

Comment: So, basically, your goal is to only show the CollectionView once it's binding is set and the CollectionView is fully loaded with the bound data?

Comment: @TedNyberg I've updated my answer with a possible way to defer the data binding until after the rest of the data is loaded. Now, I don't know whether this will actually allow to wait for the CollectionView to be fully populated before the ActivityIndicator disappears.

Comment: Thanks again! I've tried data-binding async in event handlers for both `Loaded` and `Appearing`, which would be similar to your example, but I can't quite get around the stuttering. I need to test some more to rule out if it's specific to the emulator or debug builds.

Comment: Alright, you're welcome. I think if the problem is related to the CollectionView itself, then there is not much to do about from this end. Good luck!