# How to load data on page start in .net maui

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

How do you correctly start a data load in a page in a maui application? I see examples for how to bind existing data and how to start a call on pull down or button press but not how to start a call when the page first starts.

Comment: Use the OnAppearing method

Comment: Should I await the data call or fire and forget? I don't want to block the UI.

Comment: You should await it. You can use an async override for `OnAppearing()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `OnAppearing()` override `async` and `await` any loading calls:

```cs
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    await someViewModelOrApi.LoadDataAsync();
}
```

***Note** that this will load the data every time the page appears again.*

Alternatively, you can also use the `Loaded` event of the Page:

```cs
public MyPage()
{
    Loaded += OnPageLoaded;
}

private async void OnPageLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await someViewModelOrApi.LoadDataAsync();
}
```

In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73983425/4308455) I've also described how you can load data when a Page and its ViewModel are instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

When overridden, `OnAppearing()` method allows application developers to customize behavior immediately prior to the Page becoming visible. You can write the method you want to use in `OnAppearing()`.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    // do your works
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EventToCommandBehavior in Maui Community Toolkit.

```
 <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <mct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}" EventName="Appearing" />
 </ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

In your View Model

```
private bool _isInitialized = false;
[RelayCommand]
async Task AppearingAsync()
{
    if(_isInitialized) return;
    _isInitialized = true;
    await RefreshAsync();     
}

[RelayCommand]
async Task RefreshAsync()
{
// DoSomething        
}
```